# How do I save progress in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, save

I am making an interactive fiction game using windows batch script. I sorta figured out how to do it, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it wont work.

This is the loader:

```
@echo off
cls
:load
set /p s_name=Name:
if not exist "savedata/%s_name%/" goto user_error
set /p %name%= <savedata/%s_name%/name.pok
set /p %money%= < savedata/%s_name%/money.pok
set /p %area%= < savedata/%s_name%/location.pok
echo Name: %name%
echo Money: %money%
echo Location: Area %area%
echo.
pause
exit
:user_error
cls
echo.
echo File Not Found.
echo.
echo.
pause
exit
```

and this is the save file creator:

```
@echo off
cls
set /p lnm=Your Name:
set m=700
set l=27
md "savedata/%lnm%"
echo %lnm% > savedata/%lnm%/name.pok
echo %m% > savedata/%lnm%/money.pok
echo %l% > savedata/%lnm%/location.pok
echo save complete.
pause
```

Mind you, these are just tests, but you get the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would recommend would be to reserve one character or string as a prefix for the variables you want to save/reload. This way, your save routine and reload routine are vastly simplified.

For instance, choose `$` as a prefix reserved for save/reload variables, then

```
set $>filename
```

is your save routine (every variable starting `$` will be saved in `filename` as individual lines in `varname=value` format) for instance

```
$money=700
```

And your reload routine is simply

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in (filename) do set "%%a"
```

which then reloads the variables from the file.

This way, you don't need to change anything when you want to save another variable - so long as the variablename starts `$`, it will be saved when the save line is executed and reloaded by the reload line described.

Meanwhile, please note that `/` introduces switches in `cmd` and `\` is the directory-separator. "quote strings that may contain spaces" if they are used as filenames - so "%filename%" will access the file `Fred Bloggs` if the variable `filename` contains the value `Fred Bloggs`

---

Here's an example:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

:: initial setup

SET $money=700
SET $location=27
SET $lnm=Fred Bloggs

:: (naturally, you could input LNM with a set/p if you wanted to)

:: Save the values in a file

SET $>"U:\%lnm%.pok"

:: Display values - I

echo Name: %$lnm%
echo Money: %$money%
echo Location: Area %$location%

:: Display values - II (for debugging while programming)

SET $

ECHO ============================================

ECHO Now CHANGE values

SET $money=50
SET $location=99

:: Display values - II (for debugging while programming)

SET $

ECHO ============================================

ECHO Now RELOAD values

for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a in ("U:\%lnm%.pok") do set "%%a"

:: Display values - II (for debugging while programming)

SET $

GOTO :eof
```

Note that I'm creating a file containing **all** of the `$` variables (on my `U:` drive for convenience)

The `usebackq` option is required because the filename is quoted.

Note how the original values are restored from the file. If you `type` the file, it will show lines in an obvious manner.

The key to this method is to use a prefix (`$`) to the variables-of-interest.

Comment: This seems perfect, but I keep getting blank variables. ' set /p s_name=Name: 
for /f "delims=" %%a in (savedata\%s_name%.pok) do set "%%a"
echo Name: %name%
echo Money: %money%
echo Location: Area %area% ' Maybe I'm missing something here, but it should be working. I checked the .pok files and they are right.

Comment: Forgive my stupidity, I forgot to add the $ to the echo'ed vars. Thank you sir.

Answer (score 0):

Necessary changes:

- check again `set /p %name%=` (and so on) command;
- note no surrounding nor leading nor trailing spaces with `>` and `<` redirectors (as well as with `=` assignments in `set` commands).

The loader:

```
set /p name=<savedata/%s_name%/name.pok
set /p money=<savedata/%s_name%/money.pok
set /p area=<savedata/%s_name%/location.pok
echo Name: %name%, echo Money: %money%, echo Location: Area %area%
```

The save file creator:

```
md "savedata/%lnm%" 2>nul
echo %lnm%>savedata/%lnm%/name.pok
echo %m%>savedata/%lnm%/money.pok
echo %l%>savedata/%lnm%/location.pok
echo save complete.
echo Name: %lnm%, echo Money: %m%, echo Location: Area %l%
```

Output (without some `echo`s and `cls`s):

```
==>29036918load
Name:nn
File Not Found.
Press any key to continue . . .

==>29036918save
Your Name:nn
save complete.
Name: nn, echo Money: 700, echo Location: Area 27
Press any key to continue . . .

==>29036918load
Name:nn
Name: nn, echo Money: 700, echo Location: Area 27
Press any key to continue . . .

==>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a game similar to this and figured I would share my solution.
What I did was I had my game as a batch command and I had each player in a seperate folder named "players", to save the progress I would write the batch command to call when starting back up. For example, if I only had the location variable, and money, whenever I would want to have the script save the game such as visiting a town or whatever you want, I would call a function like this each time I wanted to save:

```
call :SAVE_GAME_DATA

:SAVE_GAME_DATA
echo(
    set location=%location%
    set money=%money%
)>.\Players\%name%.bat
```

then every time you would run the script it would ask for your name and load up the batch file it wrote for your name. Like so:

```
:startup
echo Welcome to whatever game it is!
echo.
set /p name=Please enter your name:
call .\Players\%name%.bat

::rest of your code goes here
```

Of course, you would have to have logic of that if .\Players\%name%.bat does not exist then it would run the user through a character creation process and save default variables such as default location and set money=0 for example, then call the save_game_data subroutine to save the default values for the new character.